# Variables from Session Class not passing to new pages

Tags: php, session

I defined a session class,which uses values from the $_POST variable in an array called $sessionVars. When  a user logs-in a new instance of the session class is created, a construct function sets session variables.I checked that this is working correctly.Problem: When i try to access those variables from a different page the session shows that its not started and those variables are undefined. Confused cause I thought $_SESSION being a super global means its accessible all the time(i.e scope doesn't matter) . I suspect im doing something wrong when I try to access the $_SESSION variables since they are in a class. I appreciate any help..thanks in advance.

```
    class userSession{

      public function __construct($sessionVars){
      session_start();

      $_SESSION['userEmail']=$sessionVars['user'];
      $_SESSION['userID']=$sessionVars['userID'];
      $_SESSION['userFolder']='users/user_'.$_SESSION['userID'];

     }

    /*just for housekeeping. not used in application*/
    function showvars(){
    echo $_SESSION['userEmail'].'<br><br>';
    echo $_SESSION['userID'].'<br><br>'; 
    echo $_SESSION['userFolder'];
    $sessionID=session_id();
    echo '<br><br>'.$sessionID; 
   }
   }//**END USER SESSION


/*This is the login script that calls the session*/
include 'library.php'; 


  $show=new render;
  $show->index();

  if(!isset($_POST['login']) ){
  $show->usrLogin();
  } else{
     if(!empty($_POST['email'])){  
     $postVars=array('user'=>$_POST['email'],'pass'=>$_POST['password']);
     $user=new user();
     $data=$user->loginUser($postVars);


     $currSession=new userSession($data);

     }else{

     die('No data in POST variable');}

     }

 /*file upload that needs the session[userFolder] variable*/

    function file_upload(){ 

      $userFolder=&$_SESSION['userFolder'];
      echo '<hr>userFolder is : '.$userFolder;

     function do_upload(){
     if(!empty( $_FILES) ){
     echo $userFolder.'<hr>';
     $tmpFldr=$_FILES['upFile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileDest=$userFolder.'/'.$_FILES['upFile']['name'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFldr,$fileDest)){

      echo 'file(s) uploaded successfully';

      }
    else{
     echo 'Your file failed to upload<br><br>';

     }
     return $fileDest; //returns path to uploaded file
    } else{die( 'Nothing to upload');}   
   }//END FUNCTION DO_UPLOAD, 

   /*Perform upload return file location*/
   $fileLoc=do_upload();
   return $fileLoc;
  }
```

Comment: session_start() needs to occur before any output. i doubt that is the case in your code.

Comment: You need to instantiate an object of this class on *every page* that uses the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate an object of this class on every page that uses the session (or start the session manually).  Also, you'll not want that constructor, instead some other way of setting vars.  This is just for illustration of how it works with your current code, there are much better approaches:

```
class userSession {

    public function __construct(){
        session_start();    
    }

    function set_login_vars($sessionVars){
        $_SESSION['userEmail']=$sessionVars['user'];
        $_SESSION['userID']=$sessionVars['userID'];
        $_SESSION['userFolder']='users/user_'.$_SESSION['userID'];
   }
}

//page1.php
$session = new userSession;
$session->set_login_vars($loginVars);

//page2.php
//you need to start the session, either with the class
$session = new userSession;
//or session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Thank @Abracadaver...what I don't see here is how the new session on the new age gets the same session info. wouldn't page2.php get a new session id? In other words..wouldn't the session variables have to be set all over again? How do I set them once, and access them repeatedly.

Comment: When a session is started it sends a cookie to the browser with the session id, the next time it is started it asks for the cookie and uses that session id if there is a cookie/id.

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver! That worked. I'll keep testing different scenarios (like different sites logged in on different tabs), but I'll assume that teh browser is smart to handle all this for now. This was a great help though. I can't upvote your response cause I've only got a rating if 9 so far. need 15.